# SAP SAML authentication doesn't accept WS-TRUST URI token

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, netweaver, ws-trust

We have a SSO setup between SAP NetWeaver and ADFS (acting as the STS).
So, some user will login on a custom ASP.Net application and this application will request a SAML assertion from ADFS to access the SAP system.

The thing is that according to SAP documentation the relying party identifier of the SAP system is not an URL (its just a name), and that way is specified en ADFS (eg: SAPSYSTEMRPID).

How on earth I can get a token issued using WS-TRUST (which is what ADFS provides) when the AppliesTo field requires an Uri? Is there a default scheme, some convention?

I've been beating my head against the table for days now, I am obviously missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to close my own question after so much.

In the end the problem was ADFS naming of Relying Parties, once we switched the name to an URL (which took some convincing) it started working.

ADFS should be string in the name format for the RP identifier.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I'm following what sounds like a very similar process as you but the different being we have been successful in accessing the token ADFS but are having issues passing it in the request in a way that Gateway will take it... Do you have some sample code you could post showing the way you add the SAML assertation to the request going out to Gateway?  Would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I dont have access the code currently, what I can tell you now is that you need to send the token in a header. However, with SAP documentation being as brief as it is, I'd suggest that you implement the browser initiated SSO in your backend code (handling the redirects and stuff)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!  When you say pass the token in the header do you mean the token from ADFS?  Do you remember the name you gave the header?  We are tracking the traffic in fiddler and we see SAML assertions being passed around... Looks like in the end a SAP SessionId cookie is being passed to give access, guess Gateway is using that instead of a FedAuth cookie.  When we pass in the cookie we get from the fiddler traffic hard coded we can get access but not sure about how exactly to get the cookie we need by handling the redirects manually...